unable to capture the output of a remote command in powershell
I am connecting to a windows device from the host using Open-Device in Powershell.
i have to run a command in remote PC and capture the output into a variable to process further, unable to do so. tried redirecting using 'Out-String', 'Tee' Operation, Redirect the out put to a file, extract data from STDOUT etc. nothing seems to be working.
Output is printing onto the STDOUT but could not extract
Code i tried.
Open-Device <Device Serial Number>
cmdd dir


Have you tried Start-Transcript -Path "logfile.txt" / Stop-Transcript to capture stdout to a file for processing?

i tried it. did not help.

$cmdoutput = cmdd dir

$cmdoutput.Output has the required data for Remote commands. able to process the remote command output with .Output
